# qemu command line management

Tags: command-line, kvm, qemu

I'm interested in `qemu`, specifically the `kvm` feature in Linux which is operated through the command line.   I see there are a ton of features available for `gnome-boxes` and `libvirt` specifically.

My specific goal is to manage these through a command line on a BASE distribution without X.   Including adding/changing USB devices on the fly.   I know about Arch wiki and a few other sources.   But with the loss of the editors for TLDP and no real HOWTOs, along with obscure documentation it's very difficult without turning this into a discussion a discussion.

So my questions:

1. Is there another project that interacts with the `kvm` that I should be using from the command line?
2. Is there a way to get the KVM to save its state to ram when the system shuts down?
3. Mount and unmount USB devices, and CD devices from command line? monitor mode does not seem to work.
4. Any tips and pointers from the pros would be appreciated.

Here's my command line I've been working with to start the `kvm` on boot

```
screen -dmS kvm-winxp kvm \
    -cpu host \
    -smp 2 \
    -m 768 \
    -drive cache=none,file=$HOME/qemu/posready2009 \
    -vga std -nographic \
    -vnc 127.0.0.1:0,lossy \
    -net nic,model=pcnet -net user \
    -smb $HOME \
    -redir tcp:5555::22 \
    -redir tcp:5556::80 \
    -usbdevice tablet \
    -usbdevice host:058f:6387
```

Answer (score 3):

1. libvirt is great on the command line. `virsh` is the main interface. See https://libvirt.org/apps.html#command for the rest.
2. What do you want to save to RAM when which system shuts down?

`virsh autostart vmName` sets a vm to autostart.